# Get object key within function as a value

Tags: javascript, object, callback, key

I'm trying to set timeouts in javascript dynamically. Within the timeout, I rely on variables that are changed outside of the timeout callback-function. This is not a reliable practice, so I want to get rid of the dependency on this variable.

This is the excerpt of my code that applies to my question:

```
timeouts["mr"+mI] = setTimeout(function(){
    groups["mr"+mI].expired = 1;
    io.sockets.emit("invite_channel",'{"type":"pullback","mI":"mr'+mI+'"}');
},120000);
```

`mI` is changed outside of `setTimeout`, and will be identical to `mI` in the declaration of `timeouts["mr"+mI]`.

So my question is, how can I obtain the object key from `timeouts[]` (inside of setTimeout callback function), as a replacement of `mI`?

Thanks in advance!

---

I think both of the answers (by the time of writing) solve my problem. I chose the answer that uses `bind()` as the accepted answer. That's mostly because I don't (yet) understand how the `closed method` answer works. I tried to implement it, but did not get it to work. It  The other answer was fairly easily implemented.

I'd like to thank both of the answerers! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but if you want to pass `mI` to the callback and prevent it from changing. You could use the `bind()` method.

```
timeouts["mr"+mI] = setTimeout(function(x){
    groups["mr"+x].expired = 1;
    io.sockets.emit("invite_channel",'{"type":"pullback","mI":"mr'+x+'"}');
}.bind(this,mI),120000);
```

`bind(this,mI)` will pass `mI` as an argument to the function. Once the function is declared the value of `x` won't change.

Comment: Actually I just figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the current value of `mI` for the method that is invoked from the setTimeout. You can close around that value so that future modifications to `mI` don't change the value captured in the method that will be invoked in the future.

```js
var mI = Math.random();
var getMethod = function() {
  var mrMi = mI;
  return function() {
    alert(mrMi);
  };
};

var closedMethod = getMethod();

setTimeout(closedMethod, 0);
mI = 'abc';
setTimeout(closedMethod, 0);
```

Comment: Could you explain it a little? Is it the trick to return a function, and by doing so, everything you call/do doesn't get influenced by future modifications (in this case, `mrMi`)?

Comment: `getMethod` is a function that, when invoked, captures the current value of `mI` as `mrMi` and returns that value when the returned method is invoked (e.g. `getMethod()()`). In this way modifications to `mI` in the outer context do not impact the behavior of the method that will be invoked in the future (via `setTimeout`). This helps you have more confidence in the behavior of the method you are scheduling with `setTimeout` since the variables won't change between when you schedule the invocation and when it is actually invoked.